# Method or tool to simulate weighted graphs with a specified weighted degree sequence

Tags: graphs, social-network-analysis

Are you aware of a method or tool to simulate a graph with that has a specified weighted degree sequence? They would be used to generate a distribution of bootstrap replicates.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question.

A natural formalization is as follows. We have a fixed weight vector $b$ (where $b_i$ corresponds to the weighted degree of vertex $i$, that is, the sum of weights of edges incident to vertex $i$). We have the vertex - edge incidence matrix $A$ of the complete multigraph with loops. We want to sample a random point under the Lebesgue measure (in the corresponding linear subspace) from the convex polytope defined by

$$
A x = b \quad \mbox{and}  \quad x_e \ge 0 \mbox { for each edge $e$}.
$$

The general problem seems to be hard, and still an open question, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9854/uniformly-sampling-from-convex-polytopes. Answers to that question point to a "Hit and Run" method, where we perform a Markov Chain Monte Carlo random walk inside the polytope, iteratively choosing a random direction and a random point between the current point and the boundary in that direction.

Here is my implementation in R for generating small random graphs using the [hitandrun](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hitandrun/) library:

```
#install.packages("hitandrun")

# generate the incidence matrix of the complete multigraph r$A[v, e] = 1 
# if and only if vertex v is incident to the edge r$edges[e]
generate_matrix<-function(n) {
    edges <- list()
    k <- 1
    A <- matrix(data=0, nrow=n, ncol=n * (n+1)/2)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        for (j in i:n) {
           edges[[k]] <- c(i, j)
           k<-k+1
        }
    }
    for (k in 1:length(edges)) {
        i <- edges[[k]][1]
        j <- edges[[k]][2]
        A[i, k] <- 1
        A[j, k] <- 1
    }
    return (list(A=A, edges=edges))
}

sample_graph <- function(weights, n_samples) {
    n<-length(weights)        #number of vertices in the graph
    r <- generate_matrix(n)
    n_edges = length(r$edges) # =n(n+1)/2
A <- rbind(
          r$A,  # the constraint that incident edge weights for vertex i sum to weights[i]
              diag(-1, n_edges)  # add the constraint that edge weights are non-negative
             )
    dir <- c(rep("=", n), rep("<=", n_edges))
    b <- c(weights, rep(0, n_edges))
    
    sw <- sum(weights)
    # create one simple solution for the starting point
    x0 <- sapply(r$edges, function(x) weights[x[1]]*weights[x[2]]/sw)
                 
    Y <- hitandrun::hitandrun(constr = list(constr=A, dir=dir, rhs=b), x0=x0, n.samples=n_samples)
    return (list(Y=Y, edges=r$edges))
}

# res<-sample_graph(c(1,1,1), 100)
```

The library is fast for very small graphs, but the running time scales as $n^6$, so it is already more than a few seconds for $n=10$.

Other projects, for example, [volesti](https://github.com/GeomScale/volesti), might offer slightly faster sampling.

But I have no idea what the typical random weighted graph looks like for very large $n$. It would be very interesting to learn and I don't know if this has been addressed in research.